# Why is Karila's uniform different from the other girls'?

Tags: c3-bu

Most of the girls in Stella Jogakuin Koutou-ka C³-bu have pink uniforms, but Hatsuse Karila (right) has a blue uniform. Is there any reason why her uniform is a different color from everyone else's?

[image]

Comment: I have a feeling it's related to her being blonde/blue-eyed; #makes future prediction# - she's American, and a transfer student, hence her love of machine guns.

Answer (score 1):

As Clockwork-Muse mentions, it's likely this is just an example of the ["Transfer Student Uniforms" trope](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TransferStudentUniforms). This is a visual reminder of her character being "different", the stereotypical blonde hair and blue eyes of a foreigner adding to the effect.

It is not a grade uniform as another member in the club is also in second grade.

She is not actually a foreigner, having been born in Japan, though she is only part-Japanese which is enough for the trope it seems.